# When 'cron_safe_threshold' is set to 0 in settings.php, should the dropdown value on admin/config/system/cron be "Never"? or is it irrelevant?

Tags: 8, drush, cron, configuration

I've installed Drupal 8.1.6. As Ultimate_Cron won't work on this site consistently or reliably, I've decided to just use Drupal's core cron, triggered externally (via /etc/crontab) rather than using Poormanscron.

The documentation on https://www.drupal.org/cron says:

> #### Disabling "automated cron"
>
> Another way to disable cron is to add the following line to your
>   settings.php: $conf['cron_safe_threshold'] = 0; Note that this fixes
>   the setting at admin/config/system/cron to "Never", and administrative
>   users cannot override it.

I set `$conf['cron_safe_threshold'] = 0;` in the settings.php file, but when I go to admin/config/system/cron, I still see the following:

> Cron settings
>     Run cron every 3 Hours

What does *fixes the setting at admin/config/system/cron to "Never"*  actually mean?

1. The value I see is set to "Never", and can't be changed
2. The value is overwritten in the {variables} table to a fixed value equal to 0, and that the displayed drop-down value on admin/config/system/cron is irrelevant

p.s.

There's gotta be an easier way to find out available $conf settings than this

1) realize that cron in Drupal8 is actually controlled by a core module

```
cd web/core/modules/automated_cron
```

2) look for any drupal::config() assignments

```
grep -i "drupal::config(" *.module
    $automated_cron_settings = \Drupal::config('automated_cron.settings');
```

3) for each one found, get set-able vars

```
grep -i "automated_cron_settings" *.module | grep "=>"
    '#default_value' => $automated_cron_settings->get('interval'),
```

NOTE: in default.settings.php

```
 * Example:
 * @code
 *   $conf1) realize that cron in Drupal8 is actually controlled by a core module

     cd web/core/modules/automated_cron

     2) look for any drupal::config() assignments

         grep -i "drupal::config(" *.module
                 $automated_cron_settings = \Drupal::config('automated_cron.settings');

                 3) for each one found, get set-able vars
                     grep -i "automated_cron_settings" *.module | grep "=>"
                             '#default_value' => $automated_cron_settings->get('interval'),
                             ig_directories = array(
 *     CONFIG_SYNC_DIRECTORY => '/directory/outside/webroot',
 *   );
 * @endcode
 */
```

Re: automated cron, no less

and, a 'simpler' method:

```
drush cli | grep -i cron
    automated_cron.settings
    system.cron

drush cget automated_cron.settings
    interval: 10800                                                                              
    ...

drush cget system.cron       
    threshold:                                                                                   
      requirements_warning: 172800                                                               
      requirements_error: 1209600                                              
    ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This setting is for Drupal 7. In Drupal 8, the equivalent is in the config management system as `automated_cron.settings.interval`. To override it, like in Drupal 7, you can add:

```
$config['automated_cron.settings']['interval'] = 0;
```

to your **settings.php**.

To address the other question, the relevance of `automated_cron.settings.interval` & `cron_safe_threshold` is the minimum amount of time (in seconds) since the last cron run that Drupal is allowed to run again. This value is checked ([D7](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/modules/system/system.module?h=7.50#n3535) & [D8](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/modules/automated_cron/src/EventSubscriber/AutomatedCron.php?h=8.1.6#n62)) for a 0 threshold which it will interpret as `FALSE` and thus never run cron.

Comment: That does it -- I now see 'Never' autoselected in the dropdown. I see you corrected the Drupal doc page, too.  Thx.

Comment: p.s.  Where did you find that parameter/form in general for D8 vs D7?   I obviously didn't find it.

Comment: The `variable` table has been replaced with the `config` table as a part of D8's config management system.  The name keys should give you an idea of what each entry is for.